# How would I go about displaying data from an API website and putting it in text format on an activity page?

Tags: android, api, listview, html

I want to show data in a sensible form for my movie database app. The website I am using to extract data from is www.omdbapi.com. I have already created a code that extracts the title and year of the movies and displays it in a ListView form which contains items that are all clickable to another activity. I would like each activity that the ListView item clicks to to display the movie information under different headers etc.

I have been stuck on this issue all day. I'm new to coding and have no clue what most processes are called etc. Im not asking for the entire code, just instructions on what to do because I am stumped. I would be very very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the format the response is formatted you would either use (probably) an xml parser or a JSON parser and grab the info between specific xml tags or the specific keys within the JSON output.

There are thousands of examples of both methods. If you can get the title to display, then you already know how to get the other elements.

Comment: thank you for your reply. do you mind linking me to a tutorial somehow please?

Comment: Thats not how this website works but heres the link to a google search for ya!  https://www.google.com/#q=json+parser+in+java

mark my answer correct if it helped please

Comment: Also you should always post code that you already tried if you want to get the best answer